# Wildfly Infinispan cache compatibility

Tags: wildfly, infinispan

In Infinispan 6.0.x version  is there 
but what is property for in wildfly 8.2 ?

Thanks&Regards
Shankar

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand the question. Are you asking what version of infinispan is included in wildfly 8.2?

Comment: sorry. In standalone infinispan 6.0.0 <b> <compatibility enabled="true"/> </b> is available .but what is in wildfly 8 server for cache ?. Bcoz i want form a common cluster between wildfly 8 and infinispan 6.0.0  standalone server

Comment: hi any one know the ans pls help me

Comment: Compatibility can only be configured on Infinispan Server distribution, not on standalone Wildfly. Can you try with Infinispan Server?

Comment: thanks for your reply. yes i tried infinispan server. In that after placed compatibility there is no error (before set compatibility error came). So what is way/alternate for create common cluster between infinispan and wildfly ?

Answer (score 0):

A cluster between infinispan and wildfly?
Both have different purpose.
Infispan as a DataGrid and WildFly as an application server.
Both use JGroups as underlying cluster communication but you should separate it.

Or did you mean you access the cache within an infinispan server from different clients?